# How to virtualize a qnap NAS with virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, nas, qnap

I want to deploy an owncloud based cloud service at the qnap NAS TS-269L.
And i need to test it before we can use it on the production system.

there is a french site which made it possible to download a virtualbox 
disk image but the documentaion about how to use this image is very poor
or in french, so i can't get enough information out of it.

Has anybody ever been successfully virtualized a qnap NAS and could tell
me exactly how this can be acclomlish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I ask why you'd want to install it through a VM?
OwnCloud comes as a PHP web application, which can easily be installed using the QNAP's Web Server. I currently have OwnCloud installed on my TS-269 Pro with this method and it's working perfectly.

If you need any assistance getting this running, let me know.

Daxton